# how to set timestamp in python

Tags: python, dataframe, timestamp

this kind of data i have

```
0     "30-01-2018 18:46 pm"
1     "30-01-2018 01:25 am"
2     "2018-01-29 20:57 pm"
3     "29-01-2018 18:23 pm"
4     "01-29-2018 15:53 pm"
```

here is the format of all these rows and it's a  different for each row

how to remove that `am` and `pm` ??

is it possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: what is your data-type? string?

Comment: @ilja yes..it's string (i updated question)

Comment: it's going to be extremely difficult (and sometimes impossible) to differentiate between `format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %p'` and `format='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M %p'` for example: `02-03-1999 12:23 pm` could either be Feb. 3rd or March 2nd. You can't tell at all

Comment: @DavidCulbreth i know , that's why i posted it here, because we can do this with excel(change formate and make it same for all), i want to know , is it possible with pandas or not?

Comment: how do you know you're doing it right in excel? do you have something else to tell you which format you're using? My point is that with no further context, you don't even know if you're doing it right to begin with

Comment: @DavidCulbreth in excel i just need to type `%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %p` and all will convert into this format , i did it already

Comment: @jony and excel will be making an assumption about what format you're converting from. Without the same kinds of assumptions, which would be some arbitrary preference for one format over the other, this conversion is impossible. You don't know that the dates that Excel is giving you are right, unless you are manually checking the entire result. You may want to check the data that it generated for errors.This same operation is possible with pandas, but there's no further "promise" of being "more correct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have two formats that are lexically interchangeable for almost half of the dates (`format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %p`' and `format='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M %p'`), this task is logically, mathematically, and provably impossible. **You cannot determine which format is being used between these two for any date of any month before the 13th of that month.** the resulting format would be ambiguous as to whether the day or the month is the first item in the format, and is therefore impossible to transpose without some gross assumptions about the format that you're using. These assumptions may work fine, but **it is equally likely that it will parse all the dates incorrectly. This is also true in the excel-based approach you are currently using.** Please check each item of the data you generated with this method, as it likely contains improperly parsed information.

If you figure out which format you're actually using, or another way to determine the appropriate format, feel free to post another question, and I'm sure the community will help you.

If they're just strings, you can remove the `am` and `pm` from them with the following:

```py
# get your date somehow.
my_date = "01-29-2018 15:53 pm"
if my_date.endswith(" pm") or my_date.endswith(" am"):
    my_date = my_date[:-3]
print(my_date)

>>> 01-29-2018 15:53
```

Comment: hey , can i remove ("01-11-2018 12:26 pm"
"01-11-2018 10:05 am"
"01-11-2018 10:11 am"
"01-11-2018 20:38 pm"
"01-11-2018 10:59 am") am and pm from these ?? if Yes , then How ? i think this will solve this problem

Comment: Thanks alot , Man

Answer (score 0):

I would use try/except to try each of your proposed formats, until one works. Then convert it to a datetime object using strptime. Then convert that datetime object to your target format of `'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'` using strftime.